# Check if the number is round, if not then round it

Tags: python, input, rounding

I have a little python project. Just for fun. There you can add when you want to shutdown your pc. At the beginning you can choose seconds/minutes/hours, and if you choose minutes than the input number* 60 will be in the "shutdown.exe /s /t ...). (It's only working with round numbers, even than 1.5*60 will be round at the end.) I want to check if the ...*60 will be a round number or not. And if it isn't than round it and run with the round number.
 **There is the code part what i am talking about:**

```
minutes = input(":")
if minutes >= "1":
    minutes = int(minutes)
    minsec = (minutes*60)
    minsec = str(minsec)
    os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t " + minsec)
```

You can see the full code [here](https://github.com/Mateka19/Shutdown/blob/master/shutdown.py).

(I just started learning python and that's my first question, sorry if something isn't understandable.)

Comment: What do you want to ask? Please specify what you want to do with this code. IS there an error? Or anything else?

Comment: Just round it whether it needs it or not: `round(1.5*60)` -> `90`, `round(1.5*55)` -> `82`, etc..

Comment: It's only working with whole number. I get an error if I type 1.5, but I don't know why, because it will be 90 and shutdown.exe /s /t 90 is correct. And the round fuction isn't seems to work here, I tried to use it, but somehow I always got an error. (Sorry for the bad question, i am really new in stackoverflow.) I tried to edit the minsec = (minutes*60) to minsec = round((minutes*60)), but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used eval(), this worked:

```
minutes = input(":")
if minutes >= "1":
    #Minutes Calculation
    minsec = str(int(eval(minutes) * 60))
    #Shutdown with time
    os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t " + minsec)
```

Answer (score 0):

regardless if the value is round or not, just cast it to integer aka round it using int(yourvalue) the value will always be round.

Comment: But it needs to be str for the op.sys("shutdown.exe /s /t " + ....)  Error:                                     
minutes = int(minutes)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.5'

Comment: just try this   v= "shutdown /s /t " + str(int(7555.9))   os.system(v)  this works fine for me

Comment: I need multiply the number *60. And it isn't working me as well. (v = "..." + str(int(minutes*60)). I am  still getting error. I think I can't use int() for the input, if it's 1.22 and not 1 or 2. Idk why.

Comment: do the multiplying before, like in your original post  minsec = (minutes*60)  then            
v= "shutdown /s /t " + str(int(minsec))  then  os.system(v)

Comment: It doesn't worked for me because the input can't be 1.xxx, but with a simple eval() it's working. minsec = str(int(eval(minutes) * 60)) this is working finally and the old os.sys("shutdown...." + minsec) is working fine. But thanks.